# python unittest - wrong test count

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm writing a testing environment for a MOOC, and I have the following unit-test class, which examines the output of a method called `search`. The idea is to iterate over several inputs (in this case there are 2) using [`subTest`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Db2ib.png).

Here's my code:

```
import unittest
import sys
from io import StringIO
import ex1
import ex1sol

class Ex1TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.orig_stdout = sys.stdout
        self.test_lst = [4, 7, 2, 3, 1]
        self.nums_to_search = [7, 8]

    def tearDown(self):
        sys.stdout = self.orig_stdout

    def test_1(self):
        for n in self.nums_to_search:
            with self.subTest(n=n):
                # get test output
                new_stdout = StringIO()
                sys.stdout = new_stdout
                ex1.search(self.test_lst, n)
                test_output =new_stdout.getvalue().strip()
                # get solution output
                new_stdout = StringIO()
                sys.stdout = new_stdout
                ex1sol.search(self.test_lst, n)
                sol_output = new_stdout.getvalue().strip()
                # compare
                self.assertEqual(test_output, sol_output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here's what's weird - I have 2 test-cases (which I run using a for loop inside the `test_1` method. However, on the one hand my console output is:

```
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK

Process finished with exit code 0
```

On the other hand, pycharm claims that I passed 3 tests:
[image]
I can figure that the output is because eventually I run only a single test method, but I can't explain the 3-tests issue.

**My questions:**

1. What's the explanation of the behavior described above?
2. How can I make my unittest-program to display the results for 2 tests (not 1 or 3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came here googling for a similar problem and can answer your first question:
PyCharm counts every test method (here `test_1`) and every subtest as one test. You have one test method, which does two subtests (for `7` and `8`), so PyCharm displays 3 total tests.